# dask einsum failing within dask blockwise due to Ellipsis TypeError

Tags: python, dask, ellipsis, numpy-einsum, einsum

I'm not able to understand why the first one (ex1) of these two examples of code works, and the second one (ex2) throws an error:

```
A = da.rechunk(da.ones([3,10,100]), chunks=(1,10,100))
B = da.rechunk(da.ones([3,10,100]), chunks=(1,10,100))
J = da.ones(10)
K = da.ones(100)
ex1 = da.einsum('ajk,     bjk,    j,    k -> ab',
                 A,       B,      J,     K,
                          optimize = 'greedy')
ex1.compute()
```

gives:

```
array([[1000., 1000., 1000.],
       [1000., 1000., 1000.],
       [1000., 1000., 1000.]])
```

whereas

```
ex2 = da.blockwise(da.einsum, 'ab',
             A, 'ajk',
            B, 'bjk',
            J,'j',
            K,'k',
            dtype=A.dtype,
            optimize='greedy')
ex2.compute()
```

gives

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-207-2906c4cf36cd> in <module>()
----> 1 ex2.compute()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/einsumfuncs.py in parse_einsum_input()
     83                 else:
     84                     raise TypeError(
---> 85                         "For this input type lists must contain "
     86                         "either int or Ellipsis"
     87                     )

TypeError: For this input type lists must contain either int or Ellipsis
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use np.einsum in the blockwize call?